# How to play multiple tracks in video sequencer?

Tags: animation, video-sequence-editor, video

I am a beginner, so it seems to be a simple question. I have 2 tracks in video sequencer. I have added transformation to each of them so that they do not overlap. When I play animation, I see only one track, other is hidden by chess field. How to show both of tracks? (Blender 2.82a)

Comment: maybe attach some screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Done: set *Blend* option to *Alpha Over*.